# Minimizing sum with constraints

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Minimize the following sum

> $$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{x_j+1} $$
>   with constraints: for every $j, x_j\geq 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 2m, m\in\mathbb{N}$

Intuitively, it makes sense to pick $x_j\equiv 2m/n$, for we we have to keep the denominator as large as possible for every summand. How do we justify this, though?

I could view the sum as $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{x_j+1}$ and now I need to determine a stationary point of this function i.e a point $(x_1', x_2',\ldots ,x_n')=:P$ with $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}f(x_j')\equiv 0$

..but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \equiv -\frac{1}{(x_j+1)^2}$ which isn't zero for any $x_j'$.

Eventually I would like to apply the theorem which says if the Hessian is positive definite at a stationary point, then at that point, the function has a local minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with the Hessian would only work if the function as a global function $(\mathbb{R}^+)^n \to \mathbb{R}$ would have a local minimum and this minimum "coincidentially" satsifes the condition $\sum x_j = 2m$.

One possible approach would be to use [lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), but there is an even simpler solution in this case.

From the [AM-GM inequlity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) we know that
$$\sqrt[n]{\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n x_i} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n x_i$$
holds for all positive $x_i$, where equality holds if and only if all the $x_i$ are the same. Applying this inequality to $\frac{1}{x_i}$ we get
$$\sqrt[n]{\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{x_i},$$
where again equality holds if and only if all the $x_i$ are the same. From the last inequality, we can conclude

> **the inequality of the harmonic, geometric and arithmetic mean:**
>   $$\frac{n}{\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}} \le \sqrt[n]{\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n x_i} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n x_i,$$
>   where equality holds if and only if all the $x_i$ are the same.

If we apply the last inequality to $\frac{1}{x_i + 1}$, we get the following:
$$\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{x_i + 1} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n (x_i + 1)} = \frac{n^2}{n + 2m},$$
where inequality holds if and only if all $x_i$ are the same, i.e. $x_i = \frac{2m}{n}$.

Comment: Elegant, indeed! May I ask what drove you to the realm of the AM-GM inequality, did you recognize it as a similar problem or is it a reoccurring theme in problems like these?

Comment: Typically, maximizing or minimizing sums/ products under conditions that are themself sums/ products can be solved using the AM-GM inequality. Especially, when you already suspect that the minimizing/ maximizing point has identical values in all of its coordinates.