# What is the smallest value of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{d_i + 1}$

Tags: optimization

What is the smallest possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{d_i + 1}$, if the di ’s are constrained to be nonnegative real numbers and satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i = N$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2080451/42969 – it is an immediate application of the inequality between harmonic and arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality :
$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (d_i+1) \right) \left (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {d_i+1} \right) \geq n^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{d_i+1}\frac1{\sqrt{d_i+1}}\right)^2$$

From here you can see that the smallest value is $\frac {n^2}{n+N}$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.